# Different NuGet Package used in Visual Studio "stopped mode" than in debug mode

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-2022, nuget-package-restore

I identified a strange behaviour of Visual Studio.

I have an App that has the same NuGet package (but different versions) in its dependency graph.
The graph looks like this:

[image]

The ["cousing dependency"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#cousin-dependencies) rule states that version 1.9.0 should be restored, as its the lowest applicable version in my graph.

If I load the solution of "MyApp" in Visual Studio, the NuGet package "PnP.Core version 1.7.0" is used.
I know this, because when right-clicking a function and saying "go to definition", the version 1.7.0.0 of the assembly is decompiled and shown:

[image]

Also the IDE shows me errors, when I try to call a function that exists only in 1.9.0.
However, if I run the application and check the loaded DLL file assembly version with ILSpy, I see that the correct assembly (1.9.0.0) is loaded.

How can it be, that Visual studio restores a different NuGet version in stopped mode than in debugging (or building)?

Answer (score 0):

This is the csproj file on my side:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="PnP.Core.Auth" Version="[1.9.0, )" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

By using the above configurations, the version 1.9.0 will be installed successfully:

[image]

I didn't notice 1.7.0 be installed.

If you still encountered the issue, please share the information(sample code and configurations) on your side, and please explain about the groups and sharepoint in your first screenshot.